# Use namerefs in Bash(4)?

Tags: bash

Prerequisites :

- Bash Version = 4.2.46

I wrote the following code：

```sh
declare -A service1=(
  [id]=1
  [name]=foo
)

declare -A service2=(
  [id]=2
  [name]=bar
)

declare -n service

for service in ${!service@}; do
  echo ${service[id]} ${service[name]}
done
```

My expected output:

```
1 foo
2 bar
```

But I got errors when run with bash 4:

```
./test.sh: line 13: declare: -n: invalid option
declare: usage: declare [-aAfFgilrtux] [-p] [name[=value] ...]
service1 service1
service2 service2
```

I find `declare -n` is new for [Bash(5)](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/NEWS?h=bash-5.0):

> w.  The shell has `nameref' variables and new -n(/+n) options to declare and unset to use them, and a` test -R' option to test for them.

How can I implement the above code in bash 4, other alternatives？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you dereference variables like this:

```sh
for service in ${!service@}; do
  var_serviceid=$service[id]
  var_servicename=$service[name]
  echo ${!var_serviceid} ${!var_servicename}
done
```

If you want the `for` loop to look as compact as yours, you may use a dedicated function, e.g.:

```sh
foo() {
  local v=$1[$2]
  printf -- %s "${!v}"
}

for service in ${!service@}; do
  echo $(foo $service id) $(foo $service name)
done
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're wedded to this data structure, you can get the same result by assigning the array name + subscript to a variable, then dereferencing it (`${!var}`). I don't have `4.2` to test, but it should work.

v2.04

> k.  The ksh-93 ${!prefix*} expansion, which expands to the names of all shell variables with prefix PREFIX, has been implemented.

v2.00

> q.  ${!var}: indirect variable expansion, equivalent to eval ${$var}.

Here it is on my system:

```
$ bash --version | head -n 1
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (i586-alpine-linux-musl)
$ cat /tmp/so-bash4-namerefs
declare -A service1=(
  [id]=1
  [name]=foo
)

declare -A service2=(
  [id]=2
  [name]=bar
)

for service in ${!service@}; do
    id="$service[id]" name="$service[name]"
    echo "${!id}" "${!name}"
done
$ bash -f /tmp/so-bash4-namerefs
1 foo
2 bar
```

Depending on your context, maybe there's other ways to structure the data too, like putting the service number somewhere where it can be a variable:

```
declare -A \
services[id1]=1 services[name1]=foo
services[id2]=2 services[name2]=bar
```

Or

```
service_ids[1]=1 service_names[1]=foo
service_ids[2]=2 service_names[2]=bar
```

Answer (score 0):

I have bash 4.4.12 and namerefs seem to work:

```
declare -n p
p=PATH
echo $p # prints my PATH
```

In your case, I would do a

```
for service in service{1,2}
```

Comment: `for service in service{1,2}; do echo ${service[id]} ${service[name]}; done` output is `service1 service1\nservice2 service2`

Comment: @Ionsty : [Here](https://ibb.co/8Xgr2BT) is a screenshot with your example running in bash 4. Which version do you have?

Comment: @Ionsty : Of course your command gives that output! You have to do it the way I posted in my answer!!! How can you expect it to work, if you don't adapt the answer you get?

Comment: Sorry, I pasted it wrong, I wrote it according to yours

Comment: But you can see in the screenshot that it works. Maybe your bash version is lower than mine? What exactly do you get, if you put an `echo $BASH_VERSION` in your script.

Comment: Bash version is 4.2.46

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't have namerefs yet. How about updating it to at least 4.4?

Comment: OP stated that he has Bash 4.2 which does not have namerefs. This is correct because they were introduced in 4.3-alpha, which explains why you have namerefs in your Bash 4.4. I think the confusion comes from the fact the OP said namerefs were available in Bash 5 (which is correct, but that’s not the first version to have it).

Comment: @vdavid : Ah, right. I was just peeking at the title of the post.

Comment: @user1934428 thank you. Because all servers are of this version, and other programs may using bash, I don’t want to update it.